# R matplot match legend color to line color

Tags: r, plot

Here is my data:

```
name    a        b    c
alex    25.4347  18   1.81
brian   0.14354  220  1.4
chris   51.39    1.5  1.05
david   0.8465   75   1.42
eric    1.53775  82   1.81
fred    5.74352  28.5 1.92
greg    12.91    4    1.1
henry   0.2797   100  1.35
isaac   10.14    7    1.08
jacob   0.03768  480  1.85
```

I'd like to plot a lines for each person, with each person having a different formula according the a, b, and c parameters.

I write this code to plot the lines:

```
s = seq(-60,20,by =.1)
matplot(s,t(sapply(s, function(x) ifelse(dt$name == "alex" | 
                                           dt$name == "brian" | 
                                           dt$name == "chris" | 
                                           dt$name == "david",
                                         dt$a*((dt$b + x)^dt$c),
                                         dt$a*((x - dt$b)^dt$c)))),
        type = "l", lty = "solid", lwd = 2, ylab = "y axis label", xlab = "x axis title")

legend("left", legend = dt$name, lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5), col = dt$name)
```

However, I can't get the legend colors to match with the line colors. I get an error saying that the first name is not a color. Any help?

Comment: Please share data with `dput` rather that pasting a table (see the R tag description)

Comment: Can you be more clear how exactly I'd do that? (Sorry, I'm an R newbie.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `col` to valid colour in both `matplot()` and `legend()`. Suppose you want colour setting `col_set <- rainbow(nrow(dt))`, we can then do:

```
s = seq(-60,20,by =.1)
matplot(s,t(sapply(s, function(x) ifelse(dt$name %in% c("alex", "brian", "chris", "david"), 
                                         dt$a*((dt$b + x)^dt$c),
                                         dt$a*((x - dt$b)^dt$c)))),
        type = "l", lty = "solid", lwd = 2, ylab = "y axis label",
        xlab = "x axis title", col = col_set)

legend("left", legend = dt$name, lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5), col = col_set)
```

[image]

Also note how I replace your long `==` with a single `%in%`.